# Adding UIPanGesture to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `UITableView` and conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource`. I'm designing my `UITableViewCell` as a `prototype cell` in `Storyboard`. The `cell` has a `subview` called **ViewA**. When the user pans over a cell, I'd like **ViewA** to move with the gesture. I have two related questions:

**Part 1**

Should I add the `UIPanGesture` to the `tableview`or to the `cell`?

**Part 2**

If I should add it to the cells, should I do this in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?

**Part 3**

If I want to get the `cell` and then move **ViewA**, how would I go about doing this within my pan function? I currently have:

```
- (void)didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint swipeLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableview];
        NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The code you have so far looks good, you just need to replace `UITableViewCell *cell` with a custom class that has a property for "viewA".

Comment: And yes, I'd definitely go for 1 pan recognizer on the table view instead of 1 for each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yu have to make a custom class for UITableViewCell and add the panGestureRecognizer to the cell here in custom class only.

There is an excellent tutorial over here

http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views

Hope this helps.